# How can I listen to new POST methods by server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am writing some application. I am using Python 2.7 with standard requests framework.
Basically the application is just a simple client that requests GET method to some **www.example.com/goals/1** server. At first, my code simply looks like this:

```
import sys
import requests

def talker():

    resp = requests.get("http://www.example.com/goals/1")
    jdata = resp.json()
    print jdata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    talker()
```

It works without any problem. But now I want to continuously listen to any new POST methods so I could retrieve ASAP. So consider that in some x time, server uploads a new json message at **www.example.com/goals/*2*** . I have to run the code again by changing the number at the end of url. I could run a while loop which never ends and simply keeps sending the requests with incremented number until response from the server won't be 200 instead of 404 but I think it will be a bad choice and could be exhausting for a server.

So my question is, **how can I continuously listen for new POST requests from the server and request a GET method on a new POSTed message?**

Comment: "Listen for new POST request from server" is what the server does, there is no way to do that on the client side. If you want to enumerate existing resources, implement a server side API to list them.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. If you control the server, you have a number of options: you can provide an endpoint that returns a list of resources available (which you could poll), or that broadcasts/pushes new data to you (which would require you running a server to receive it), but there's no magic way to know that the server has received a request.

Comment: @JimStewart What if I continuously wait for a new POST by sending a new request until I get 200 instead of 404?

Answer (score 0):

You could poll for new data using something like this:

```
def talker():
    resource_id = 1
    while True:
        resp = requests.get('http://www.example.com/goals/%i' % resource_id)
        if resp.ok:
            jdata = resp.json()
            print jdata
            resource_id = resource_id + 1
        time.sleep(60)
```

This is just a proof of concept; you'll probably want to make it smarter. I included a sleep in there because otherwise it will spam the remote server (which I assume you don't own). Use your discretion as to how frequently you should check for new data.

This assumes that resource IDs are sequential, and that once you've seen one, you want to look for the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flask, a package for making basic websites in python to listen to post requests. A code like this would do the job. This assumes that the data being sent is a json file. Other options are possible as well.

This code could be sufficient depending on what you're doing:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
        return '', 200
    else:
        abort(400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: This is for the server I believe

Comment: @Edmund do you mean the item sending the information when you say server? I used this code to set up a program which would wait for messages sent by a website to then work with that information. Is that what you are looking for?